# Task Parallel library vs Native Thread Synchronization

Tags: c#

This question may be subjective but i just want to know when to use TPL and when to use native thread based synchronization (evnts, wait handles).

Will the native thread synchronization techniques be obsolete going forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TPL wherever you can because it's a cleaner, more declarative way to express your needs for parallelism.

MSDN explains *"The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available. In addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool, cancellation support, state management, and other low-level details. By using TPL, you can maximize the performance of your code while focusing on the work that your program is designed to accomplish."*

See also http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx which details the benefits of 'Data Parallelism' and other TPL benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel extensions works great for parallelizing small tasks. Parallel extensions really provide code constructs. The ForEach for example replaces the normal foreach statement, but instead will execute it in parallel. That's the level Parallel extensions is meant to be used for.

When you're creating a full fledged multi threading application (e.g. a web server), normal threading and synchronization will still have to be used. Of course, WCF and IIS already solve such problems for you.

Of course, there is the middle ground that is solved by thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

Task Parallel library is not primarily intended for Thread Synchronization, it designed for facilitating much more tasks. TPL is designed to facilitate following steps:

1. Partition it into small chunks.
2. Execute those chunks in parallel via multithreading.
3. Collate the results as they become available, in a thread-safe and performant manner.

And only third item is related to thread synchronization. And of course you still can use known thread synchronization primitives to perform collation result in thread-safe manner (for example using class Parallel, when you should collate this result yourself).